# Twitter4j Stream Shutdown

Tags: scala, twitter, stream, twitter4j

I am using the Twitter stream to sample on certain filtered tweets. However I want to extract only a small set of tweets so I am using time to control when I shutdown the stream. Meanwhile I write to a file. However, until I quit the the program, the stream continues and does not shutdown. Any reasons why? I am using scala to do this, here is my code:

```
def simpleStatusListener = new StatusListener() {
    def onStatus(status: Status) { 
      appendToFile("/tmp/stream.txt",status.getText) 
    }
    def onDeletionNotice(statusDeletionNotice: StatusDeletionNotice) {}
    def onTrackLimitationNotice(numberOfLimitedStatuses: Int) {}
    def onException(ex: Exception) { ex.printStackTrace }
    def onScrubGeo(arg0: Long, arg1: Long) {}
    def onStallWarning(warning: StallWarning) {}
    }

val twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance

twitterStream.addListener(simpleStatusListener)

val now = System.nanoTime
if((System.nanoTime-now)/1000000 > 10){
      twitterStream.cleanUp
      twitterStream.shutdown
    }
```

Comment: If you're going to shutdown your stream after some time (e.g. after 10  seconds) you have to use Timer. Your if block almost surely executed only once and when it is executed the `System.nanoTime-now` difference is just a few nanoseconds, thus stream is never shutdown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bit where you close the stream is likely to execute immediately after the line where you compute the `now` variable. So it's very unlikely that the if condition `(System.nanoTime-now)/1000000 > 10` will hold. Here's a solution:

```
def simpleStatusListener = new StatusListener() {
  def onStatus(status: Status) { 
    appendToFile("/tmp/stream.txt",status.getText) 
  }
  def onDeletionNotice(statusDeletionNotice: StatusDeletionNotice) {}
  def onTrackLimitationNotice(numberOfLimitedStatuses: Int) {}
  def onException(ex: Exception) { ex.printStackTrace }
  def onScrubGeo(arg0: Long, arg1: Long) {}
  def onStallWarning(warning: StallWarning) {}
}

val twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance

twitterStream.addListener(simpleStatusListener)

//scheduling the closing of the stream
val interval = 10 * 1000000

val timer = new Timer() 

val cancelTask = new TimerTask {
  def run() {
    twitterStream.cleanup()
    twitterStream.shutdown()
  }
}

timer.schedule(cancelTask, interval)
```